# Django admin unregister Sites

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've been trying to unregister the admin for sites in django by doing the following:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

admin.site.unregister(Site)
```

However this gives me an error stating that "Site" is not registered (even though it showed up in admin before).

If I try doing the following I get no errors but "Site" stays in the admin:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

admin.site.register(Site)
admin.site.unregister(Site)
```

I need the sites app and cannot take it out of INSTALLED_APPS in settings. However the admin for it is utterly useless to me.
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Checked the order or `INSTALLED_APPS`? The `django.contrib.sites` app will have to come *before* your own app in the settings

Comment: That worked! Thank you, I had no idea the order mattered. How do you even debug something like this!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting is important.

When Django starts it will import the applications in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the order they are defined (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded). In your example above you were unregistering `Site` before Django had the chance to register is it.

There isn't much you can do in terms of troubleshooting except for reading the logs very carefully. After staring at them for a while you either become one with Django and understand it all, or you come here like the rest of us ;-)

My `INSTALLED_APPS` usually start with the `django.contrib` apps, then any 3rd-party applications, then my apps at the bottom. I only change this if I have a *very* good reason to.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, this makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: Note that adopting this pattern of placing your own apps at the bottom (as I have) results in your app templates being superseded by your 3rd-party app templates (took me an hour to figure that one out).  I'm still not sure what the right fix for this is, unless there's a way to unregister a model lazily.

Comment: Putting your app first is important when overriding templates, etc. From the docs: `When several applications provide different versions of the same resource (template, static file, management command, translation), the application listed first in INSTALLED_APPS has precedence.`